# How can I add a custom toolbar to the touch keyboard in UWP apps?

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, uwp

I'm having an input form with multiple TextBox elements and I would like to add a "Next" button on the touch keyboard that allows the user to advance to the next TextBox.

I've tried experimenting with the CommandBar as BottomAppBar (hide/show it based on touch keyboard visibility) but it doesn't really fit the purpose I think. What's the way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to customize software keyboard in UWP app.

> I've tried experimenting with the CommandBar as BottomAppBar (hide/show it based on touch keyboard visibility) but it doesn't really fit the purpose I think. What's the way to do it?

I think you've made a good decision to use `CommandBar` as BottomAppBar, and to hide/show it based on touch keyboard visibility. There is no facility for defining custom keyboard layouts in an application, so a bottom `Commandbar` is the best choice in this scenario under the current condition.